# How to implement global data in SvelteKit SSG

Tags: sveltekit

I'm building a fan website for an online card game using SvelteKit and `adapter-static`. Since it's a site for a card game, I need cards data to be available globally across the site, which can be acquired via an API.

I tried store in some ways but not worked.

```js
//error: Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari14" + 2 overrides)
export const cards = readable<CardData[]>(await fetch("https://some-api/cards/")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => result["result"]));


//also not works
export const cards = writable<CardData[]>([]);

async function fetchData()
{
    let data = await fetch("https://some-api/cards/")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => result["result"]));
    cards.set(data);
}
fetchData();
```

Currently I'm fetching it in topmost `+layout.server.ts` and saves in context with `setContext()`.

```js
//src/+layout.server.ts
import type { CardData } from "$lib/card";

export const prerender = true;

export async function load({ fetch, url })
{
    const response = await fetch("https://some-api/cards/");
    const result = (await response.json())["result"] as CardData[];
    console.log(`fetch - ${url}`);

    return {
        cards: result
    };
}
```

```html
<!-- src/+layout.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
    import "../app.postcss";
    import type { LayoutData } from "./$types";
    import { setContext } from "svelte";

    export let data: LayoutData;

    setContext("cards", data.cards);
</script>

...
```

However, after checking the logs, I found out that the data is being fetched on every page.

```
fetch - http://sveltekit-prerender/releases/2022-10
fetch - http://sveltekit-prerender/about
fetch - http://sveltekit-prerender/cards
fetch - http://sveltekit-prerender/
fetch - http://sveltekit-prerender/card-usages
fetch - http://sveltekit-prerender/cards/u318
...
```

There is no need to fetch it every time since all the necessary information is included in the data. So it would be great if I could fetch it only once and use it globally on the website. The readable store method worked properly, but only when targeting esnext and I'm not satisfied with it. Is there any other way to achieve this in SSG?

Comment: (You should not need to set a context at all; layout data is inherited by pages and merged with the page `data`.)

Comment: Did you turn off the client side router? Layout data should only be loaded once per full page load (unless invalidated). Client-side navigation should not trigger it as far as I know.

Comment: @H.B. No I didn't. I think I wrote it a little confusingly, the logs are only printed during build time. Getting data via `+layout.server.ts` causes fetch to be performed on every page and slows down the build time, so I'm looking for a better way to implement global data

Comment: Do you want the data to be fixed at build time?

Comment: @H.B. I think the data is already fixed since my entire website is prerendered. My site works well as it is, but what I don't like is that the build time takes long and current method does not look efficient

Comment: Pre-rendering does not preclude dynamically fetching data later. It all depends on what the requirements are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For static data you could just fetch it *before* the build and then inject it as a build constant via [`define`](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#define).

```js
export default defineConfig(async ({ command, mode }) => {
  // may need a package if not included in used Node version (< 18)
  // e.g. undici (used by SvelteKit)
  const cards = await fetch(...)

  return {
    // ...
    define: {
      CARDS: JSON.stringify(cards),
    }
  }
})
```

Any occurrence of CARDS will then be replaced with the respective data. You could declare a simple module to only have it in one place:

```js
export const cards = CARDS;
```

There is no point in using a store if the data never changes.

For TypeScript you will either have to declare the `CARDS` variable in a `.d.ts` file or ignore the resulting error from `CARDS` being unknown.